# Unable to create user in Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Within a Firebase `onCreate` trigger, I'm creating a user with roughly this code:

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth'

const auth = getAuth()

await auth.createUser({ email: 'test@test.com' })
```

In my `index.ts` file, I'm initializing like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'

initializeApp()
```

When I deploy the function and it's triggered I get this error:

> Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property has insufficient permission to access the requested resource. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to authenticate this SDK with appropriate permissions.

Which is strange because I already have 25 deployed functions, have a service account set up, and have already been using the Auth SDK just not to create users.

Looking at the IAM roles for the Firebase Admin SDK principal (firebase-adminsdk), it already has the "Firebase Authentication Admin" role which has "Full read/write access to Firebase Authentication resources." which seems sufficient to create a user?

The only thing I can think of is possible the Firebase Cloud Functions are using a different principal which doesn't have the necessary permissions? The instructions in the error message point to creating a service account which I already have since I'm using the Auth SDK functions but doesn't mention anything specific for creating users, so I'm not sure what the actual issue is.

Comment: Have you tried initialize with `firebase-admin` like follows: `import * as admin from "firebase-admin";` and `admin.initializeApp();` ?

Comment: Hi does above posted comment help ?. If so then I will post as an answer, so other community members will also get answer to this question.